# ngModel not updating variable in dropdown menu

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update the variable 'selectedValue' in my typescript through this HTML code:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"  >
            <option *ngFor="let item of clients" [value]="item" >{{item}}</option>

          </select>
          <p>here is the the item :  {{selectedValue}}</p>
```

Here, the list clients is just a list of strings.

I tries changing value to ngValue, relocating the < p > tag and changing the variable name.

This is what my ts file looks like:

```
export class BasicAccountComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts : Account[];
  clients: string [];
  selectedItem: string;
  columnDefs = [
    ...

  ];
  private defaultColDef;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { 
    this.defaultColDef = {
      filter: true,
      width: 185,

    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.clients = [];
    this.selectedItem ='';
    //this.getAccountsByClient(this.selectedItem);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.CalculatePageSize();
    this.getAccounts();
  }
  getAccounts() {
    this.accountService.getAccounts().subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accounts = accounts;
      this.accounts.forEach(account => {
        if (account != null){
          if (!this.clients.includes(account.client)){
            this.clients.push(account.client)
          }
      }
      })
      });

    }
  getAccountsByClient(client: string){
    this.accountService.getAccountsByClient(client).subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accounts = accounts;
      });
    }


}
```

the variable selectedValue does not update from an empty string.

Comment: Your ts property is named `selectedItem` not `selectedValue`

Comment: where are you updatig selectedValue in your ts file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable named `selectedValue` in your .ts file. You need to rename `selectedItem` to `selectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

you have bind selectedValue in html but declare selectedItem in ts file.